# Car door lock cover plate is stuck open

Tags: honda, accord, locks, door

The metal cover plate on my driver side door lock is stuck open:

[image]

It's supposed to be closed like this:

[image]

Would it be okay to leave it like that, or would the inside of the lock eventually rust and stop working?  (I have a 1997 Honda Accord.)

Comment: We've had a '92 Accord with the plate missing for many years, and never had trouble with it. It freezes and snows in the winter, and park outside in all weather.

Comment: Is the plate literally gone, or just stuck open. It's easy to bend the cover, causing the hinge to stick. If it's just stuck open, you can remote the lock core by taking it out from inside the door panel, pull the cover off, and bend it flat so the hinge unsticks.

Comment: I hadn't taken a close enough look earlier - it looks like it is just stuck open.

Comment: Keep it lubricated and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a locksmith so I see this all the time. Its probably not stuck. More likely the spring or the cover itself has slipped out of position which means it would need to be taken apart to be fixed. If you use it often enough with the key then you really do not need to do anything and it will be fine. If you use a remote usually and rarely the lock then you may want to lubricate it once in awhile and cycle it with your key to keep the wafers from getting stuck by built up of dirt/corrosion.